# Using OpenRecordset in Access

Tags: vba

Why if I am using this code fragment I get out only one record?

```
Dim sav1 As DAO.Database
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Set sav1 = CurrentDb

Set rec = sav1.OpenRecordset(Text2)
```

Comment: Text2 from textbox is Select kravas_mašīna.Marka From kravas_mašīna; but in table kravas_mašīna record count is 5.

Comment: How did you check that the returned recordset has only one record?

Comment: Using For i = 0 To rec.RecordCount, but now i put rec.MoveLast and get RecordCount=5. However it don't solv all my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RecordCount` property is not reliable. It is useless until you scroll all the `Recordset`.

```
Set rec = sav1.OpenRecordset(Text2)
rec.MoveLast ' <--- necessary to have all records in the `RecordCount`
rec.MoveFirst ' <--- re-seeks the recordset to its beginning
For i = 1 to rec.RecordCount ' <--- now you will have the correct count
```

It is usually recommended to not use the `RecordCount` property, but to scroll the recordset record-by-record in a loop, i.e.

```
Do Until rec.EOF
  ' ...
  ' do something with the current record
  ' ...

  rec.MoveNext ' <-- move to next record and loop
Loop
```